# Mercurial templates: have "{branches}" return "default"?

Tags: templates, mercurial

What's the simplest way to have `hg ... --template '{branches}'` return `default` instead of an empty string when the changeset being printed is part of the default branch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not found an in-template way to do that.  If I'm in a shellscript I do something like:

```
BRANCH=$(hg log --revision 0 --template '{branches}')
echo ${BRANCH:=default}
```

Though if you have the [excellent hg prompt extension](http://sjl.bitbucket.org/hg-prompt/) in place you could do:

```
hg prompt '{branch}'
```

Comment: Dang. Yea, I'd thought about that… But it kind of sucks, and relies on being inside a shell script (ex, it doesn't work in `notify.template`).

Comment: `hg log --debug` shows a line with `extra: branch=default` (or whatever branch), so the information _is_ available.  Looking at the default style file shows it using an `{extras}` keyword, which I can't find mention of in the documentation.

Comment: oh the info is definitely available, I just don't think it can be exposed via the template system.  Certainly sed or shell can be used to produce it from extras or whole cloth.